# How to access the td's having images without using id or class in the td..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

We have a HTML newsletter like this....

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
  <td>
     Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
   <a href="#">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
   </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i need to add `style="font-size:0%"` for the td's having images.
we are not using id's or any class in the HTML.
So how to do using javascript..??

Thanks!!

Comment: xpath? `//td[descendant::img]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a naive approach without jQuery

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
    tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    tdsWithImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(tds).filter(function (td) {
        return td.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0
    });
    tdsWithImages.map(function (td) {
        td.style.fontSize = "0";
    });
```

Comment: you just forget to set style on tdsWithImages elements, but not that hard to do +1

Comment: @Orlando thanks, But i am using your code.. 

function change(input, output) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    try {
        div.innerHTML = input;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
        return;
    }

var table = div.getElementsByTagName("table"),
    tds = div.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    tdsWithImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(tds).filter(function (td) {
        return td.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0
    });
    tdsWithImages.map(function (td) {
        td.style.fontSize = "0";
    });

    output.value = tdsWithImages;
}

Comment: i don't understand your comment :/

Comment: @Orlando I got the desired output.. but the html existing html styles got overwritten.. here is the code..

'function change(input, output) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
try {
div.innerHTML = input;
} catch (e) {
alert(e.message);
return;
}
var table = div.getElementsByTagName("table"), tds = div.getElementsByTagName("td"),tdsWithImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(tds).filter(function (td) {
return td.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0
});
tdsWithImages.map(function (td) {
td.style.fontSize = "0%";
});
output.value = div.innerHTML;
}'

Answer (score 5):

Use `.has()`:

```
var $tds = $('td').has('img').css('font-size',0);
```

Comment: didn't know about `has()`, looks very useful

Comment: Need add class, not determine having images

Comment: @chethan  tagged with jquery. And jquery is javascript. In pure javascript, should iterate with some statements...

Comment: @chethan  sorry didn't saw you were the OP. So why tag a question with jquery if you don't want to use it???

Comment: @chethan - You had tagged it with jQuery, which can only mean that a jQuery solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('td:has(img)').css('font-size','0%');
```

or

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    if ( tds[i].getElementsByTagName('img').length )
         tds[i].style.fontSize = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a slightly different approach, using jQuery:

```
// note: 0 doesn't require a unit
$('img').closest('td').css('font-size', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just? $("td img").each()

Comment: Because `font-size` isn't a very useful CSS property on images?

Answer (score 0):

`$('img').closest('td').css('font-size','0%');`

Comment: I edited my answer: originally had "find()" instead of "closest()". I brainfarted. An upvote would be nice - thanks! :-)